# Css shape z-index and border

Tags: html, css, shapes

Im trying to make an a css shape but im experiencing problems with the border of the rhombus

The border of rhombus shape appears when it shouldnt appear...

[Here](http://dabblet.com/gist/5744736) you have the code with css and html.

Sorry for my poor english.

thanks in advance

EDITED:

I dont want the top border in the rhombus...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLrn9.png

Comment: sorry but I can't get you.. what's your expected result

Comment: You should copy here the relevant part of your code. Also, you should make more clear what is your expected result, it's difficult to understand what is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand your question quite well, but if the result is similar to this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiXEE.jpg
Just add *z-index:-1* to you *div#barra:after* element ...

If this is not what you want, please explain us what is that you want to achieve.

/*EDIT*/

id="barra" need these modiications:

```
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(196, 196, 196, 1) 0%,rgba(147,147,147,1) 100%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgb(148, 146, 146);
```

And barra:after needs this:

```
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(155, 155, 155, 1) 0%,rgba(147,147,147,1) 100%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%);
    z-index:-1;
```

And that should be it ... :)

Comment: The problem is that i dont want the top border of the rhombus as u can see in the screenshot. http://i.imgur.com/bAAPlv4.png

Comment: Ok ... here is your solution ... 
http://imgur.com/YM0p4Oz
You need to adjust your colors a bit... 
I have edited my post so you can see the code...

Comment: You might need to modify it a bit, but you get the point... :)